# Why don't ports resolve correctly for localhost and {my server name}?

Tags: networking, ip, port, localhost

I set up VisualSVN Server, and SQL Server on my local machine.

VisualSVN was set up to use https://dell/svn/ as the repository root.
I was connecting to SQL Server using "localhost".

At some point I made a change to some Windows setting, and now these don't resolve to the right ports.

For example, using "https://dell/svn/" in TortoiseSVN fails, but "https://dell:8443/svn/" works.

Similarly in SQL Server connection strings, "localhost" fails but "localhost,1433" works.

Interestingly, 127.0.0.1 and ::1, without any port specified, also work.

Anybody have any idea what I could have done wrong or how to fix it?  These ports used to work automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could just modify the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file to point dell to 127.0.0.1

like below:

127.0.0.1       dell